# typescript check dynamically if string is a property of complex object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I really need to be able to check dynamically if aa is a property of my complex object called validations

```
const check = 'propertya' + 'a'; // result of a complex calculation that returns string 'propertyaa'

validations= {
    'a' : {
      'propertyaa': 'ax',
      'ab': 'ay',
      'ac': 'az'
    },
    'b' : {
      'ba': 'ax',
      'bb': 'ay',
      'bc': 'az'
    }
  };

if (this.validations.a[check] === undefined) {  ...
```

Error is:

```
element implicitly has an any type because type '{ ' propertyaa': string, 'ab': string, 'ac': string; }' has no index signature
(property) 'a': {
    'propertyaa': string;
    'ab': string;
    'ac': string;
}
```

Curiously the static (not dynamic) variant works `if (this.validations.a['ab']) {`

Comment: Both tests are working fine for me...

Comment: This bit gives you the error: `this.validations.a[check]`? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: My test working well.

Comment: Yes that bit: this.validations.a[check] gives the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler solution and really the only one that works for me so far:

```
cartoons = {
      'producers': {
          'Disney': 'Walt Disney',
          'PIXAR1': 'John John'
       }
    }

const check = 'Dis' + 'ney';
    const y = (<any>this.cartoons.producers)[check]; // notice the cast to any
    alert(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go one of two routes. You can either add an index signature to your validation properties:

```
type Indexable = { [name: string]: string }
const validations = {
    'a': {
        'propertyaa': 'ax',
        'ab': 'ay',
        'ac': 'az'
    } as Indexable,
    'b': {
        'ba': 'ax',
        'bb': 'ay',
        'bc': 'az'
    } as Indexable
};

const check = 'propertya' + 'a';
if (validations.a[check] === undefined) {
}
```

You could also just cast the property to `Indexable` when you use it:

```
if ((validations.a as Indexable)[check] === undefined) {
}
```

You could also use `any` instead of `Indexable`, but the `Indexable` defined above provides more type safety then `any`

Another option is to assert that the string `check` is in fact a key for the value of `a`:

```
if (validations.a[check as 'propertyaa'] === undefined) {
}
```

**Edit**

If you go with the first option, a helper function can help avoid the need for the type assertion on each property of `validations`:

```
type Indexable = { [name: string]: string }
const validations = createValidations({
    'a': {
        'propertyaa': 'ax',
        'ab': '19',
        'ac': 'az'
    },
    'b': {
        'ba': 'ax',
        'bb': 'ay',
        'bc': 'az'
    }
});
function createValidations<T>(o: { [P in keyof T]: T[P] & Indexable}) : typeof o {
    return o;
}
const check = 'propertya' + 'a';
if (validations.a[check] === undefined) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html)...

```
interface ComplexObject {
    [index: string ]: string | ComplexObject;
}

const check = 'propertya' + 'a';

const validations: ComplexObject = {
    'a' : {
      'propertyaa': 'ax',
      'ab': 'ay',
      'ac': 'az'
    },
    'b' : {
      'ba': 'ax',
      'bb': 'ay',
      'bc': 'az'
    }
  };

if (this.validations.a[check] === undefined) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I get: Element explicitly has an any type because type string | ComplexObject has no index signature. Am i missing something? thank u! Now i get this even if i check for this.validations.a['propertyaa']